Who is "he" in a sentence from Daudet's The Last Lesson?
In this line from "The Last Lesson" by Alphonse Daudet:

But he had the courage to hear every lesson to the very last.

Who is "he" here, Franz or M. Hamel? Initially I thought it should be Franz, but my teachers and other books told me that "he" here refers to M. Hamel. I can't understand why: M. Hamel is the teacher, so why would he hear the lessons - he would teach the lesson and students would hear the lesson. Can you please clarify with suitable and convincing points because I am unable to understand.
Here is the story (PDF).

As a side note, "Franz" is the speaker in the story. He would therefore not refer to himself as "he" - he instead refers to himself throughout as "I".

The original French text (La Dernière classe) says,

Tout de même, il eut le courage de nous faire la classe jusqu’au bout.

Literal translation:

All the same, he [Mr. Hamel] had the courage to teach us the class to the end / all the way through.

In other words, in spite of the fact that the Prussians would no longer allow the teaching of French the next day, so it would be Mr. Hamel's last day at the school, he still had the courage to teach his French lessons until school was out.
The translation of the above sentence in the PDF interprets "faire la classe jusqu’au bout" as teaching each subject (grammar, writing, history) that morning as as a lesson. In other words, Mr. Hamel teaches each of these lessons until "the end" (presumably the end of what he had planned to teach). However, the French term "classe" is singular, so "every lesson" is a rather free translation. A teacher can indeed "hear his pupils' lessons", but this phrase gives the impression that he is checking what they have learnt, whereas in the phrase "faire la classe", the suggested direction of communication is purely from teacher to pupils.

The translation is wrong. He teaches the class as a whole until the end of this time teaching at the school, which is that day.

@Lambie Which translation? The one in the question or the one in my answer?

Sorry, my bad.  Both are wrong.

@Lambie Where is my translation supposedly wrong? The French text I cite is not explicit about his "teaching time", so why should I put that in the translation?

If you look at my answer, you will see. I don't want to argue. faire la classe is just: teach class, as in: I teach class every morning. It's not teach us the class. You did say the translation you provided was literal...

That sentence, by itself, gives no clues as to who or what “he” refers to (could have been a stuffed bear or an animal of some type or even a sci-fi alien).
But the pdf gives the required context to make it unmistakable.
That sentence is the start of a new paragraph, the paragraph preceding it starts with:

Whenever I looked up from my writing I saw M. Hamel sitting motionless in his chair and gazing first at one thing, then at another

And then does not mention anyone or anything to which a pronoun would be applied (except his sister, who would get a “she”).  Thus the subject of the “he” is inarguably “M. Hamel“, whoever or whatever he maybe.
Generally a pronoun, once used, continues to refer to the same person until a new person/object of a sentence is introduced. It may be possible to construct a sentence where that is not the case, but it will be atypical at the least.

There is a mistake in the translation of the sentence.

Tout de même, il eut le courage de nous faire la classe jusqu’au bout.

In any event, he had the courage to keep teaching his class to the end.


[to the end of the time he still had in the school that day; he would leave the next day].
class here does not mean a single subject. It means to teach all the pupils in his class a series of subjects until the time was up for teaching them (for example, the afternoon or morning). To remove the ambiguity, I've used keep teaching instead of just teach.
"he" is Mr. Hamel, the teacher. The only male referred to is him, as of the previous paragraph.
